# Svelte Store. Spread syntax is not merging - just adding

Tags: store, svelte

I am trying to add some brocolli to my basket in the svelte store I have created. My code adds the brocooli to the basket but then duplicates the baskets and adds a whole new basket to my store. Not sure if the problem is caused by my lack of understanding of javascript or svelte.

**Desired result**

```
Basket 1 OrangePineapple Basket 2 BananaApplePlumwalnuthazelnutnutmegbroccoli
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**

Basket 1

- Orange
- Pineapple

Basket 2

- Banana
- Apple
- Plum
- walnut
- hazelnut
- nutmeg

Basket 2

- Banana
- Apple
- Plum
- walnut
- hazelnut
- nutmeg
- broccoli

## Link to svelte codebox where you can view and run code

https://svelte.dev/repl/80d428000a3f425da798cec3450a59d4?version=3.46.2 
if you click the button you see that my basket is duplicating. I am just trying to add the brocooli to the basket.

code below

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const storeBaskets = writable([
   {
     "name": "Basket 1",
     "items": ["Orange", "Pineapple"]
   },
   {
     "name": "Basket 2",
     "items": ["Banana", "Apple","Plum","walnut","hazelnut","nutmeg"]
   }
 ])
//Local functions
export const add = (item,basketIndex) => { 
       storeBaskets.update(val => {        
        const newItems = [...val[basketIndex].items, item]
        const newBasket = {'name':val[basketIndex].name,'items':newItems}
        val = [...val,newBasket]
       return val
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not need to spread, because it's an array, you'r spreading the existing items of the array and then adding the new basket to it. You can `map` and replace by `basketIndex`, like:

```
export const add = (item,basketIndex) => { 
        storeBaskets.update(val => {
         const newItems = [...val[basketIndex].items, item]
         const newBasket = {'name':val[basketIndex].name,'items':newItems}
         
        return val.map((basket, i) => i === basketIndex ? newBasket : basket)
    })
}
```

([Working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/dcd7cfbd97aa42639deedf8d8cd96b4b?version=3.46.2))

Comment: Thanks! Both answers are great I selected this as the most usefull due to the link to the REPL. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
val = [...val,newBasket]
```

With this line you're copying the previous store value and adding the newBasket "on top". That's how the spread operator works with arrays

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let n = 4

let arr2 = [...arr, n]

console.log(arr2) // [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]
```

I wonder if you might have thought of the different behaviour when spreading an object, where an already existing entry might be overriden if the key already exists

```
let obj = {key: 'value'}
let key = 'newValue'

let obj2 = {...obj, key}

console.log(obj2) // { key: "newValue" }
```

To make your code working you could replace the line by `val[basketIndex] = newBasket`

```
export const add = (item,basketIndex) => { 
    storeBaskets.update(val => {        
        const newItems = [...val[basketIndex].items, item]
        const newBasket = {'name':val[basketIndex].name,'items':newItems}
        val[basketIndex] = newBasket
        return val
    })
}
```

Or, instead of spreading, simply push the new value directly to the according nested array in just one line

```
export const add = (item,basketIndex) => { 
        storeBaskets.update(val => {        
        val[basketIndex].items.push(item)
        return val
    })
}
```

Comment: I got two great answers I wish I could select them both. Thanks!

Comment: Push!  Keep it simple, make it work.